# Syntax error for no apparent reason in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have no idea why i have a syntax error in python at all here is my code I am a beginner this is python 3.8.1 shell:

```
name = str(input("What is your name?"))
age = int(input("How old are you?")) # <-- error here
siblings = int(input("How many siblings do you have?")) 
print("Your name is", name)    
print("You are", age., "years old") 
print("And you have", siblings, "siblings")
```

This very weird. I don't understand why it is happening look at the letter a in age.

Comment: Hi, I've edited your question to make it readable. Please review it, and [edit] as necessary. In particular, I've assumed you don't have all the commands in one line. If you did, that may be the problem --- Python is finicky about whitespace. Always make sure to include the actual error message you get. See [ask].

Comment: Next time post the full error traceback please

Answer (score 1):

It is just `age` not `age.`

```
name = str(input("What is your name?"))
age = int(input("How old are you?")) # didn't find the error on this line
siblings = int(input("How many siblings do you have?")) 
print("Your name is", name)    
print("You are", age, "years old")  # I changed this line
print("And you have", siblings, "siblings")
```